# return blank if field is blank

Tags: calculated-column

I have the following calculated column that returns the "Max End Date" field using the following format YYYY/MM/DD.

=YEAR([Max End Date])&"/"&MONTH([Max End Date])&"/"&DAY([Max End Date])

Although this is working well when there is actually a value in it, when there is no value it returns a nonsense *1899/12/30*. I would like it to return nothing if the "max end date" field is empty. I know there is a function **ISBLANK** that accounts for this, but how do I go about integrating it in my existing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint DateField is a counter

So 1899/12/30 is not *Nonsense* but day 0

```
=IF( [Max End Date] 
     , TEXT( [Max End Date] , "yyyy/mm/dd" )
     , "Where is the end date?"
   )
```

https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

### Update 1

Sharp observation from @SPArchaeologist in the comments

```
=TEXT(0,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

returns 1899/12/30

```
=TEXT(1,"yyyy/mm/dd")
```

returns 1899/12/31

Comment: not meaning to say you are wrong at all, but... Any idea why it is 1899/12/30 and not 1899/12/31?